# ROR# How do I check if integer is present in numrange column or not

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with numrange field
Ex: RangeModel(data_range: numrange, owner_id: uuid)

I want to find if the integer value is present in the range or not
something like:  owner.range_models.where(.in?(data_range))

Comment: Have you read the PostgreSQL documentation on numrange operators and functions?

Comment: What is actually your question? To find and load all instances of that model those data_range cover a certain value? Or to check if a specific already loaded instance's data_range covers a certain value? Or do you simply need a method returning a boolean indicating if there is any data_range in the table covering that specific value?

Answer (score 0):

You can add validate a number by using ActiveModel::Validations, like this:
Inside your model

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  validates :num, numericality: { in: 18..65 }
end
```